# proof of construction of angle 360/17

Tags: geometric-construction

One construction for a 17-sided polygon is shown below.

```
Construct a circle with diameter and radius OC perpendicular to AOB
Construct OD = OC/4
Construct DA
Bisect angle ODA twice to construct angle ODE (= ODA/4)
Construct angle EDF = 45 degrees
Construct a semicircle with AF as diameter, intersecting OC at G
Using E as center and EG as radius, construct a semicircle intersecting AB at H and K.
Construct HL and KM, both perpendicular to AB
Angle LOM = 720/17. Bisect LOM to get 360/17.
```

Prove this.

Comment: Prove what exactly? Furthermore, are you talking about $7$ or $17$?

Comment: We have to prove that angle LOM thus formed will be equal to 720/17.

Comment: sorry, it was 17 instead of 7.

Comment: I guess you want to prove that this construction works - have you tried anything, or looked for references? I agree this is an interesting problem. But we can help you better if you tell us what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried this: take radius 1. start getting length of segments one by one. but then it was very much complicated. i have tried coordinate but it didn't give me anything

Comment: Isn't it what Gauss solved, the construction of a regular heptadecagon? See Wikipedia for links about the heptadecagon!

Comment: I saw there was no proof about this on wikipedia.